# Setting up Redis cluster dynamically with uneven number of master and slaves

Tags: redis

I want to set up 1 master and 2 slaves or 1 master and 1 slave for certain number of servers. So it will have 20 nodes and 45 instances. I'm wondering how I can set it up so that it's like this:

```
"127.0.0.1",|1M2S|port 40000~40002  e.g. 127.0.0.1:4000(master), 127.0.0.1:4001(slave)127.0.0.1:4002(slave)
"127.0.0.2",|1M2S|port 40000~40002
"127.0.0.3",|1M2S|port 40000~40002
"127.0.0.4",|1M2S|port 40000~40002
"127.0.0.5",|1M2S|port 40000~40002
"127.0.0.6",|1M1S|port 40000~40001
"127.0.0.7",|1M1S|port 40000~40001
"127.0.0.8",|1M1S|port 40000~40001
"127.0.0.9",|1M1S|port 40000~40001
"127.0.1.0",|1M1S|port 40000~40001
```

I also want the slaves distributed across servers. I belive this --replicas will automatically try to distribute the slaves so that the master and slaves are not on the same server/IPadress.

```
./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 \ 127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005
```

But that only works if there are even number of slaves and masters. How do I make it so it will put 2 slaves on server 1~5?
I also have to set up another cluster that has `8M11S|40700~40718` so I would like to know if there is a way of distributing these simply as opposed to manually getting the ID's of master from a different server and adding a slave.

Comment: Any particular reason you want 8 masters and 11 slaves topology ? It would make more sense to have 9 masters and 10 slaves topology. You can achieve that my specifying replicas argument in the command to 1. Redis will first distribute the slots between 19/2=9 masters, and then assign the remaining instances (10) as slaves, with one lucky master getting 2 slaves.

Comment: @nsuneja with 8 master and 11 slaves, 3 masters will get 2 slaves. The only thing is I want to SPECIFY which of the servers will have the 2 slaves. I don't want to manually find the ID of masters then add each slave to it since I have a lot of servers and instances

Comment: Any reason for picking specific masters ? From redis cluster point of view, all masters are equal, and will get equal share of the keys, unless you change the hashing scheme on the client.

Comment: @nsuneja There are multiple servers and I want to spread out the number of masters in different servers. And I'm also creating  clustering for each different buisness logic. E.g. clustering for apple instances, orange , watermelon, and etc.

Comment: So, the underlying principle behind a redis cluster is that that all nodes are homogeneous. If hetrogenity is required (for eg. Some keys should be more available than the others, i.e. different replication factor), you need to create multiple clusters. Your usecase seems more aligned with multiple clusters scenario. Also, note that redis-trib creates a single cluster on the host:port list, and it will by default, keep the cluster uniform. If you need anything on top of it, you would need to use redis cluster commands to get the topology you want, although in your case I wouldn't recommend it.